# Adding Flutter_localizations to Flutter App, cause stopping to generate .g dart files

Tags: flutter, build-runner, flutter-localizations

After adding flutter_localizations in my App and running the command 'flutter packages pub
run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-output', no .g dart files are generated.

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
build_runner: ^2.4.6

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_modular/flutter_modular.dart';
import 'package:sindico_virtual_app/app/shared/theme/default_theme.dart';
import 'package:sindico_virtual_app/app/shared/widgets/glow_blocking.dart';

class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //
    // SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));

    return MaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationParser: Modular.routeInformationParser,
      routerDelegate: Modular.routerDelegate,
      title: 'App',
      theme: defaultTheme(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      scrollBehavior: GlowBlockingScrollBehavior(),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [const Locale('pt', 'BR')],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: does the generation of .g file stop after implementing a localization? do you try to generate it again after removing the localization temporarily for a just test whether it works or not?

Comment: Yes, right after installing the flutter_localizations package, the generation of .g files was interrupted. Regarding the test you suggested, I tried here removing the location, running flutter clean and flutter pug get again, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Okay, do you try to use different versions of the build_runner? As you said maybe the build_runner is the problem.